# c++ accepting 0 into while loop illegally

Tags: c++, while-loop

Here is the objective: "Write a c++ program which prompts the user to enter some numbers and finds the minimum, maximum, and count
(number) of the entered numbers separately for the positive and negative numbers. It then prints out this information
in the correct format. Entering 0 should terminate the input sequence and cause the results to be displayed.

My problem is, when I run the code through www.cpp.sh, it seems to be storing the 0 that I use to end the sequence to a maximum or a minimum variable (posmax and negmax or posmin and negmin). My while loop's condition is number_entered !=0, so 0 shouldn't even be going into the loop...
[if the first 3 in the sequence are negative and the last 3 are positive;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3MuY.png)   [if the first 3 in the sequence are positive and the last 3 are negative](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj1z5.png)

Stranger still, the 0 being stored as a minimum or negative only seems to happen to the last sequence of variables entered.

Relevant code:

```
int main()
{

double number_entered, posmax, posmin, negmax, negmin;
int positive_count, negative_count;
positive_count = 0;
negative_count = 0;
posmax = 0;
posmin = 0;
negmax = 0;
negmin = 0;

//before it goes into a loop it will do the following:
cout << "Entering 0 will terminate the sequence of values.\n" << endl; 
cout << "Enter a number: ";                                 
cin >> number_entered;   //stores input to number_entered

 if (number_entered > 0) //if positive  
 { 
    posmax = number_entered;   //needs to be initialized before use in loop
    posmin = number_entered;   //needs to be initialized before use in loop
 }
 else if (number_entered < 0) //if negative
 {
    negmax = number_entered;   //needs to be initialized before use in loop
    negmin = number_entered;   //needs to be intiialized before use in loop
 }

while (number_entered !=0) //will keep looping as long as the while condition is true
{ 
  if (number_entered > 0) //branch if number_entered is positive 
  {  
        if ( number_entered > posmax) //sub-branch to compare to get max 
    { 
        posmax = number_entered; //if number is larger than the current max, it gets stored as the new max 
    } 
    else if ((number_entered < posmin)||(posmin == 0)) //sub-branch to compare to get min; since posmin is initialized to 0 it needs to be updated
    {  
        posmin = number_entered; //if number is less than min than it gets stored as the new min
    }
  positive_count++; //under main if branch for if the number is positive, add to positive_count
}
else if (number_entered < 0) //branch for if number_entered is negative
{  
    if ( number_entered > negmax) //sub-branch if number_entered is more than the max
    { 
        negmax = number_entered; //it then gets stored as the new negmax
    } 
    else if ((number_entered < negmin)||(negmin == 0)) //sub-branch if number_entered is less than min; since negmin is initialized to 0 it needs to be updated
    {  
        negmin = number_entered; //it then gets stored as the new negmin
    }
    negative_count++;
}
cout << "Enter a number: "; //prompts for input again after it is done counting, and comparing to store a max and min
cin >> number_entered;
} //end of while loop

if (number_entered == 0) 
{
    cout << endl;
    if ((negative_count > 0) && (positive_count > 0))   //for situations where it received both positive and negative values
    {
    cout << "There were " << negative_count << " negative values entered, with minimum "<< negmin << " and maximum " << negmax << endl << endl;
    cout << "There were " << positive_count << " positive values entered, with minimum "<< posmin << " and maximum " << posmax << endl<< endl;
} 
else if (negative_count > 0 && positive_count == 0) //for sitautions where only negative input was received
{
    cout << "There were " << negative_count << " negative values entered, with minimum "<< negmin << " and maximum " << negmax << endl << endl;
    cout << "No positive numbers were entered" << endl;
} 
else if (positive_count > 0 && negative_count == 0) //for situations where only positive input was received 
{ 
  cout << "There were " << positive_count << " positive values entered, with minimum "<< posmin << " and maximum " << posmax << endl<< endl;
  cout << "No negative numbers were entered" << endl;
} 
else if (negative_count == 0 && positive_count == 0) //for if only 0 was received
{
cout << "No positive numbers were entered.\n"
      << endl
      << "No negative numbers were entered.\n"
      << endl;
} //end of nested branching if-else if statement
} //end of if statement
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your entering a `0` at the end then `cin >> number_entered;` is going to store it into `number_entered`.

Comment: You might want to delete this then.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally, but maybe I posted the answer badly and that was why I didn't get the answer I needed.

in order to get a max that wasn't 0 for the negative values, I simply needed to move my || (negmax == 0) condition to the correct if statement (it was on the minimum branch).

There were no other issues with the program.

Answer (score -2):

Because your initial values are zeros. There is no way that you will enter number lower (for positives) and higher (for negatives) than zero.

Comment: They are unconditionally assigned by the extra input statement before the loop begins.